# Regex validation numer and alphabet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i wanna validating an student name input, that input can:

- contain alphabets and number, but cant only number
- and not case senstiive

Example :

- Wawan Cakra 20
- 14 James Smith
- For You Page

code here :

```
name: Yup.string()
  .min(4, "Minimum 4 characters!")
  .max(30, "Maximum 30 characters!")
  .matches(/\b[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*?\b/, "Only alphabets and numbers are allowed for this field!")
  .required("Name is required!")
```

Comment: im using formik and yup for validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following regex pattern here in case insensitive mode:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9 ]{4,30}$
```

This matches any input which contains at least one character, optional numbers and spaces, and has a length of between 4 and 30 characters.

```js
var inputs = ["Valid", "21 Jump Street", "1234", "abc", "abcdeghijkabcdeghijkabcdeghijka"];
inputs.forEach(x => console.log(x + " => " + /^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9 ]{4,30}$/i.test(x)));
```